# Download a node (and its associated files as a zip archive)

Tags: files

Looking to create a system whereby users can upload print quality images, have them resized for web, but allow admin users to download the contents of a particular node and download the highres images and field texts as a zip archive... what would be a good starting point for this?  A particular module?  Build a custom module?

Answer (score 3):

I put together a proof of concept module real quick, which exports files based on assumptions about `field_type` (image, file and media).

To test it out, put the following code in a custom module, then go to */export-entity/node/`nid`* to export a node.

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function export_entity_menu() {
  $items['export-entity/%/%entity_object'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'export_entity_page_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(2, 1),
    'load arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Export entity page callback.
 *
 * @param object $entity
 * @param string $entity_type
 *
 * @throws EntityMalformedException
 * @throws EntityMetadataWrapperException
 * @throws Exception
 */
function export_entity_page_callback($entity, $entity_type) {

  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
  list($id, $vid, $bundle) = entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity);

  $file_fields = field_read_fields(array(
    'entity_type' => $entity_type,
    'bundle' => $bundle,
    'type' => array('image', 'file', 'media'),
  ));

  $field_files = array();
  foreach ($file_fields as $field_name => $field_config) {
    $files = $wrapper->{$field_name}->value();
    if ((int) $field_config['cardinality'] === 1) {
      $files = array($files);
    }
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      $field_files[$file['fid']][] = $field_name;
    }
  }

  $export_filename = drupal_tempnam(file_directory_temp(), 'entityexport_');

  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  if (!($zip->open($export_filename, ZipArchive::CREATE))) {
    throw new Exception(t('Unable to create zip archive'));
  }

  $entity_data = entity_var_json_export($wrapper->raw());
  $zip->addFromString(sprintf('%s_%d.json', $entity_type, $id), entity_var_json_export($entity_data));

  // Load and attach all files/file entities
  $files = file_load_multiple(array_keys($field_files));
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $folder = reset($field_files[$file->fid]);
    $file_path = drupal_realpath($file->uri);
    $zip->addFile($file_path, $folder . '/' . $file->filename);
    $zip->addFromString($folder . '/' . $file->filename . '_entity.json', entity_var_json_export($file));
  }
  $zip->close();

  // Copy archive to public storage and redirect to its URL.
  $public_uri = file_default_scheme() . '://entity-export/' . $entity_type;
  file_prepare_directory($public_uri, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
  $public_uri .= '/' . basename($export_filename) . '.zip';

  $public_path = file_unmanaged_move($export_filename, $public_uri);
  $public_url = file_create_url($public_path);

  drupal_goto($public_url);
}
```

Note that this should be done using a batch callback and/or a cron-job, especially if you expect to get alot of data - which may cause the script to time out and/or run out of memory (although it really shouldn't).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to put this example together. It is a great starting point.

Answer (score 0):

[pclzip](https://www.drupal.org/project/pclzip) might be a good place to start. It's only in dev for 7, but you could always take a look at the back end and see what they're doing, then use that to write a custom module off of it if it doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Or take a look at the module mentioned at the pclzip module page: Download (https://www.drupal.org/project/download). It's more up to date (stable 7.x release)